# Reporting on Google Ads Conversion Custom Variables

Tags: google-ads-api

I have created custom variables in Google Ads and I am trying to automate reporting for them. However, I cannot seem to find a Google Ads documentation on the appropriate API endpoints that will enable me to pull these.

I tried these links:

1. https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/conversions/conversion-custom-variables
2. https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/fields/v14/conversion_custom_variable_query_builder

I would appreciate any guidance. Thanks!